# "$K'$-structures" as defined by Bourbaki

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, field-theory

The following is written in Bourbaki' Algebra p.317-18:

> Let $K'\subset K$ be fields, $V$ a right $K$-vector space and $V'$ a
> subset of $V$ which is a $K'$-subspace of $V$. The following
> conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. The $K$-linear mapping $\lambda$ of $V'\otimes_{K'}K$ into $V$ such that $\lambda(x'\otimes\xi)=x'\xi$ for all $x'\in V'$ and $\xi\in
>     K$, is bijective.
> 2. Every $K$'-linear mapping $f'$ of $V'$ into a $K$-vector space $W$ can be extended uniquely to a $K$-linear mapping $f$ of $V$ into $W$.
> 3. Every basis of $V'$ over $K'$ is a basis of $V$ over $K$.
> 4. There exists a basis of $V'$ over $K'$ which is also a basis of $V$ over $K$.
> 5. The $K$-vector space $V$ is generated by $V'$ and every subset of $V'$ free over $K'$ is free over $K$.
>
> Every $K$'-subspace $V'$ of $V$ satisfying these equivalent conditions
> is called a $K'$-structure on $V$.

I can't find anything corresponding to this in mainstream literature. The section in which the study of these spaces appears is titled "Restriction of the field of scalars in vector spaces". Is there another name for these spaces? Can I find them in other books besides Bourbaki? I am having some trouble following Bourbaki's treatment and so I would appreciate a different source that discusses them.

Comment: You could try these notes https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf